# how to change <?php the_category() ?> template?

Tags: categories

this function produce this html

```
<ul class="post-categories">
   <li><a href="#" rel="category tag" class="text">test</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" rel="category tag" class="text">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

but i need this html

```
<ul class="post-categories">
<li>
    <a href="#" rel="category tag" class="text">            
        <span class="hover-toggle">Farm to Cup</span>
        <span class="hover-toggle">Farm to Cup</span>            
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" rel="category tag" class="text">            
        <span class="hover-toggle">Farm to Cup</span>
        <span class="hover-toggle">Farm to Cup</span>            
    </a>
</li>
```

i s there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

you could use this snippet, and modify the output string accordingly.

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $output .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category->name ) . '</a>' . $separator;
    }
    echo trim( $output, $separator );
}
```